# PHP file_get_contents sudden failure on server

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I was using file_get_contents() to fetch information from an external URL. It was working perfectly on the server before. But now, somehow it fails to work on the server. (No changes in the codes.) It keeps giving me the error: `failed to open stream: Connection timed out`.

I have tested it on `localhost` and it works perfectly. I have checked `allow_url_fopen` option, it is still `On`.

So, what could be the reason(s)?

Comment: May be the source server blocked your host?

Comment: @SajithNair Thanks for your reply. Oh well... so is there any way to check if that really happens?

Comment: Do you have ssh access to your server?

Comment: Another reason could be, your timeout setting in `php.ini`. Check the value of `default_socket_timeout` in your `php.ini`. You can also override it by giving `ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 900);` in your php code (in case your timeout is low and you are trying to access a big file)

Comment: Well, I am afraid I do not have ssh access. And I have just tried to set the timeout setting, but it didnt work as well, no matter I use `file_get_contents` or `cURL`. And I just tried to access other sites like `Google` and that worked properly. So I guess it is really quite likely that the target site has blocked the host...

Answer (score 0):

file_get_contents does not work well at all with getting remote files and should not be used. It does not deal with slow network connections or redirects, and does not return error codes. You should use curl instead to fetch remote files.

There is an example in the manual for curl_exec:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php

Comment: Can you give any proof for this?

Comment: IN another Case,To use file_get_content to read a web address allow_url_fopen has to be set to on. Have you checked that?

In Another case 
If you do not have access to the php.ini on a hosted service you can turn it on from the .htaccess file using

php_value allow_url_fopen On

Comment: Sorry but I already mentioned that I have `allow_url_fopen` set to `On`.

Comment: these are some quastion already check in stackoverflow  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18447827/file-get-contents-connection-timed-out-for-some-contents

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455403/failed-to-open-stream-connection-timed-out-error-themoviedb

Comment: @krish thanks for your help. I have tried to use cURL, but it didnt work as well.

Comment: ok i will search this things and i got the answer then i will tell u